# Create dynamic cron WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I am creating a plugin to create wordpress crons dynamically. The problem I have is that It only works on the last added. I have put this code (static) to test if it works and it is not working, only one is executed and the other is not.

```
    add_action('init', function() {

        if( !wp_next_scheduled( 'girls_0' ) ) {
            wp_schedule_event( time(), '1min', 'girls_0' );
        }

    });

    add_action('init', function() {

        if( !wp_next_scheduled( 'animals_1' ) ) {
            wp_schedule_event( time(), '1min', 'animals_1' );
        }

    });

    add_action('girls_0', function() {
        $tipo=1; $busqueda='girls';
        require_once(X_PLUGIN_DIR.'sitios/1.php');
    });

    add_action('animals_1', function() {
        $tipo=1; $busqueda='animals';
        require_once(X_PLUGIN_DIR.'sitios/1.php');
    });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you look at `wp-includes/cron.php` you'll see Wordpress cron do not run concurrently and will not run more than once every one minute.

```
    // don't run if another process is currently running it or more than once every 60 sec.
    if ( $lock + WP_CRON_LOCK_TIMEOUT > $gmt_time )
    return;
```

Wordpress cron is also "pseudo" cron service, so events are fired only if someone visit page. It can be real user. It can be web crawler too, but it's not sure, cron event will start.